# Android Project build failed while using NDK over Jenkins

Tags: android-ndk

May someone help me to understand the root cause for build failure during Jenkins build of my application. The error seems coming  from native C code which is integrated in our project from Android NDK.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the compiler segfaulted. Are you on the latest NDK?

Comment: Yes i am using latest NDK (Latest Stable Version (r14b)).

Comment: In that case, we're shipping r15 beta 2 at I/O (17 May). It will have an updated Clang, and these sort of issues are usually transient, so it will probably be fixed in that release.